# In tkinter, the canvas size settings seem to stop working when the canvas is used as a master for another widget. Is there a way to get around this?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So, this is a simplified form of the problem I'm facing:

The following code produces a canvas whose size is just big enough to accomidate the label, even though it was configured to be 400 by 400

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

label = tk.Label(canvas, text='foo')
label.pack()
```

If the last two lines are omitted, then the canvas is the size that I would expect it to be (400 by 400), but it does not contain the label, which is something that I want it to contain.

As I said, this is a simplified form of my problem, I actually want to put several widgets into the canvas, but this behavior is the cause of my problem. Is there a way to make the canvas the size that I want (in pixels) *and* use it as the master for other widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is setting the size of the root window:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

label = tk.Label(canvas, text='foo')
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you can use the `grid` method, using `row/column configure` and `sticky` argument will do the rest of the job. I don't know `pack` enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this :

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_minsize(400,400)
label = tk.Label(root, text='foo')
label.pack()
```

But you would loose the ability to resize the window under 400x400.
There is also this possibility but i'm not sure that it works:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
label = tk.Label(canvas, text='foo')
label.pack()
```